ILP for Subset sum problem in C# using Gurobi
I'm trying to solve a variation of the subset sum problem via Gurobi optimizer in C#.
It seems to be working, but I was wondering if there's any room for improvement in my current implementation?
public static void SolveSubsetSumProblem(List<decimal> setA, List<decimal> setB)
{
    try
    {
        using GRBEnv env = new GRBEnv();
        using GRBModel model = new GRBModel(env);

        int numSetA = setA.Count;
        int numSetB = setB.Count;

        // Convert decimal lists to double arrays for Gurobi
        double[] setADouble = setA.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
        double[] setBDouble = setB.Select(p => (double)p).ToArray();

        // Create variables
        GRBVar[,] x = new GRBVar[numSetA, numSetB];
        for (int i = 0; i < numSetA; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < numSetB; j++)
            {
                x[i, j] = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, $"x_{i}_{j}");
            }
        }

        // Variables for unmatched elements from set A and set B
        GRBVar[] unmatched_set_a = new GRBVar[numSetA];
        GRBVar[] unmatched_set_b = new GRBVar[numSetB];
        for (int i = 0; i < numSetA; i++)
        {
            unmatched_set_a[i] = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, $"unmatched_set_a_{i}");
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < numSetB; j++)
    {
        unmatched_set_b[j] = model.AddVar(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, GRB.BINARY, $"unmatched_set_b_{j}");
        }

        // Set objective: Minimize unmatched elements in set B
        GRBLinExpr obj = new GRBLinExpr();
        for (int j = 0; j < numSetB; j++)
        {
            obj.AddTerm(1.0, unmatched_set_b[j]);
        }
        model.SetObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE);

        // Add constraints
        // 1. Each element in set B is either matched once or unmatched
        for (int j = 0; j < numSetB; j++)
        {
            GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
            for (int i = 0; i < numSetA; i++)
            {
                expr.AddTerm(1.0, x[i, j]);
            }
            expr.AddTerm(1.0, unmatched_set_b[j]);
            model.AddConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, 1.0, $"set_b_use_{j}");
        }

        // 2. Each element in set A is either exactly matched or unmatched
        for (int i = 0; i < numSetA; i++)
        {
            GRBLinExpr expr = new GRBLinExpr();
            for (int j = 0; j < numSetB; j++)
            {
                expr.AddTerm(setBDouble[j], x[i, j]);
            }
            expr.AddTerm(setADouble[i], unmatched_set_a[i]);
            model.AddConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, setADouble[i], $"set_a_match_{i}");
        }

        // Optimize model
        model.Optimize();
    }
    catch (GRBException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error code: {e.ErrorCode}. {e.Message}");
    }
}

The gist of it is the following:

We solve the subset sum problem for entries in set A.
Additionally, elements in set B that have been used to solve the subset sum problem for a given target/element in set A, can no longer be used to solve the subset sum problems for future A elements.


I think the proposed solution should work fine. However, I have minor suggestions which might (or might not) improve readability:


double[] setADouble = setA.Select(i => (double)i).ToArray();
double[] setBDouble = setB.Select(p => (double)p).ToArray();

could be rewritten as
var setADouble = setA.Cast<double>().ToArray();
var setBDouble = setB.Cast<double>().ToArray();


You don't have to pass names when creating variables or constraints. If you don't need names, simply use null as name.
expr.AddTerm(1.0, x[i, j]); can be simplified to expr.Add(x[i, j]);
model.AddConstr(expr, GRB.EQUAL, 1.0, $"set_b_use_{j}"); can be written as model.AddConstr(expr == 1.0, null);.


I think you might able to use addVars to create a variable array and addTerms to build each term in the constraint, instead of writing explicit for loop by yourself.
The following links are the reference from gurobi website. FYI!
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/cs_model_addvars.html
https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/cs_lex_addterms.html
